# How to update an object and push into an array at the same time in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema as below

```
var FriendsSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String
  }
  firstName: String,
  lastName:  String,
  previousEmails:[{
    email:{
      type:String
    }
  }],
  createdDate:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
  },
  updatedDate:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
  }
});
```

What I am trying to do is, that on an update, if the 'email' changes, I would like to update the 'email' field to the new value being passed in, and push the current 'email' value into the 'previousEmails' array.

I am able to accomplish this in two steps as follows:
1) Update the object by id, and set all fields except the array 'previousEmails'
2) If the 'email' field of the object was changed, push the old value into 'previousEmails' array.

My question is, is it possible to do this in one step ? So I have the $push and $set as party of my query ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the above answer is close. I got it working by doing the following, which is close but also adds the $set, which is not included above

```
Friend.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {$set:{email: req.body.email}, $push: { previousEmails: this.email } }
}, {new: true}, function(err, friend){
    if (err){
        console.log(err); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: exactly the problem I was facing also. Your solution solved it. thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

```
Friend.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {email: req.body.email, $push: { previousEmails: this.email } 
}, {new: true}, function(err, friend){
    if (err){
        console.log(err); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.