# How to update and Push in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have taken this schema from  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ContactSchema = module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    index: {unique: true}
  },
  messageCount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default:0
  },
  messages: [
  {
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    msg: {type: String, required: true}
  }]
}, {
    collection: 'contacts',
    safe: true
});
```

I can push message by doing this

```
let result = await Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id,
        {$push: {"messages": {title: title, msg: msg}}},
        {new : true})
```

But I want to increase messageCount also in single step where

```
messageCount can be random also but point is to push and update
```

I am expecting both message and messageCount to update in single query using any mongoose functions

Answer (score 0):

After Looking to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865649/how-to-update-an-object-and-push-into-an-array-at-the-same-time-in-mongoose) and tried on my doubt

```js
let result = await Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(
  id,
  {
    messageCount:10
    $push: {"messages": {title: title, msg: msg}}
  },
  {
    new : true
  }
)
```